# Cisco switch port to ip address mapping

Tags: cisco

How can I pull a list of the IP addresses that each device has that is connected to the switch. Example:

Port: gi1/15 = 192.168.1.4

Port: gi1/16 = 192.168.1.5

What command do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a command for this directly. You can do show arp to pull the ARP table to show IP's that correlate to MAC addresses, and then do show mac-address-table to pull the MAC table to see what ports each MAC address is coming from.

Comment: And if it's a layer 2 switch you may need to find the nearest layer 3 device to show the arp table.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a switch port mapper, but I've found them to give hit or miss results.

http://www.manageengine.com/products/oputils/switch-port-mapper.html

http://www.solarwinds.com/products/toolsets/switch_port_mapper.aspx

http://www.netscantools.com/spmapmain.html

http://www.packettrap.com/product/pt360_pro.aspx?fid=switch_port_mapper

http://www.switchportmapper.com/